# {% extend %} {% block content %} {% endblock %} in an HTML page does not work

Tags: html, extend

I am trying to extend a navbar so it appears in several pages. When I insert {% extend %} {% block content %} {% endblock %}, it only appears as text - the code dosen't work.
Here is my Navbar that I want to extend:
[image: Navbar]
This is how it appears in the browser:
[image: navbar browser]

This is the html file I want to include my navbar in:
[image: code Text file]
How it appears:
[image: text browser]

I want to inherit my navbar, but only the code text appears in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

`{% extend %}` and so on have no special meaning in HTML.

The syntax is clearly from some template engine. Maybe [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/).

You'll need to pass your source code through the template engine and use the HTML generated from it.

Comment: Indeed.  Are you maybe using flask's render_template function from your view?